# Can I use two ASP.NET Core Identity in one project MVC?

Tags: sql, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.0

I have two different entities `Staff` and `Customer` that have different attributes and behaviors, each of them has a separate login system. I'm intending to use the ASP.NET Identity to manage the login, role, claim etc. of each entity.

Is it possible and best practice to use each Identity system for each entity?  My idea would be something like: `AspNetUser` will become `Staff` and `Customer`, `AspNetUserRole` will become `StaffRole` and `CustomerRole`, etc.

What will be the appropriate solution to my problem? (Without merging the `Staff` and `Customer` to `User` entity).

Comment: This is a pretty difficult question to answer without specific details about what is different between the two.  You can definitely setup a ASP.NET Core to handle two very different login paths and authorization flows but you may or may not need two different `Identity` instances.

Comment: Hi Pace, thanks for replying my question. My general idea is a e-commerce project which has 2 type of users: `Staff` and `Customer`. I decide to split them up to two different login system because each of them has their own action on the system. The `Customer` also very differences from the `Staff` such as the `Staff` will be addded by the manager, while the `Customer` can create their own account by using email or social login. The `Staff` will have particular role while the `Customer` just only themself. Can you show me how to control the login path and authorization flows with one Identity?

Comment: Anyone who has faced the same problems, help me, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything you've described so far can be accomplished with a single standard identity instance using role based authorization with a `staff` role.  Both your `Staff` and `Customer` object can have a one-to-one reference to an `AspNetUser` instance.

You can have two registration methods, `RegisterNewUser` and `AddStaffMember`.  The `RegisterNewUser` method will just create a new `AspNetUser` instance while the `AddStaffMember` method will create a new `AspNetUser` instance and add an `AspNetRole` instance with the value of `staff`.  The `RegisterNewUser` method will be accessible anonymously while the `AddStaffMember` method will gate access to only allow users with the `staff` role

Comment: Wow, I've never thought about the one-one relationship in this situation. But you said *"The RegisterNewUser method will be accessible anonymously"*, but what if I have the function that requires only `Customer` authenticated to perform, such as Review for the product. The Anonymous Customer (Non-authenticated) shouldn't be allowed to do that. I'm thinking about creating one more role for `Customer` in `AspNetRole`, and then check for the `Customer` is authenticated or not. What do you think about my approach?
Anyway, your comment is opening my mind. Thank you so much!

Comment: If only customers (and not staff) can access the method then your approach sounds good.  If you just want to require the user be authenticated (both customer and staff are valid) then you don't need an extra role.  You can just use `Authorize` with no parameters and it will enforce that.

Comment: Nice. Thanks for your thought!